# Nvidia-driver-410 depends on nvidia-driver-418?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 19.04

When trying to install `nvidia-driver-410` Ubuntu 19.04 tries to install several additional packages including `nvidia-driver-418`. In this case the newer driver is being used which cause a major issue on my platform (the audio is not working via HDMI).

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a reason for this dependency?

I have already tried to explicitly exclude this dependency, but it fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-410 nvidia-driver-418-

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-driver-410 : Depends: nvidia-driver-418 but it is not going to be installed
```

Update:
Just found out that `nvidia-driver-410` is a transitional package for `nvidia-driver-418`, so it partially makes sense. I still don't know why there is no way to install the older driver though.

Comment: The command you posted actually installs both and I think that's a very bad idea. Try purging all the Nvidia drivers you have installed so far and install only the recommended version.

Comment: Did audio work on previous version? If so which version did it work with?  If not what CPU and GPU do you have?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia note the hyphen `-` at the end of the second package name. It explicitly prevents the package from being installed in this transaction (https://serverfault.com/a/663803/521400). Otherwise providing only `nvidia-driver-410` would include the `nvidia-driver-418`. I know that it seems like a stupid idea and that's the point of my question.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it worked on the 410 driver. I was able to install it on Ubuntu 18.10 before (without 418). No idea why there is such dependency. Either there is some explanation or there is a bug in the package.

Comment: @pkubik So you upgraded 18.04 or 18.10 to 19.04? Or you did a clean install of 19.04 and now want to downgrade Nvidia driver from `418` to `410`? Sorry I'm on Ubuntu Unity 16.04.6 LTS with Nvidia driver `384` and loving it. I'm not that familiar with upgrade woes and have never used a non-LTS version.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129483/install-nvidia-drivers-with-cuda-10-0-ubuntu-18-04-and-tensorflow-gpu-1-13

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Clean install. I need newer driver for CUDA 10. The sound on 3xx works fine for me too.

Comment: @pkubik Will `396` or `390` work. They seem to be popular choices with those getting hung up on `418`.

Comment: The nvidia driver versions that are available in 19.04 are 390 and 418. The 410 package is a dummy package that depends on the 418 one.

Comment: `390` works but do not support CUDA 10. It seems that I need to install 410 manually or look for some ppa that provide real 410. I don't get this packaging scheme. Why not just a single nvidia-driver package with different versions?

Comment: The reason for this dummy 410 package is to provide smooth upgrades from 18.10 to 19.04. A 18.10 user will have 410, and when they upgrade to 19.04 the 410 package gets upgraded to the dummy one, and the 418 package is installed. If the dummy package didn't exist, they would be left with the old 410 from 18.10, and would need to install the new one manually.

Comment: @fkraiem So they need to do it because they are no longer going to provide 410 package, but they would like to smoothly replace each package X for Ubuntu 18.10 with package X for Ubuntu 19.04. Thank you, it makes sense now. I guess a single `nvidia-driver` package with different versions would be more cumbersome for the user because apt does not display all available versions by default.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using ppa, but the transitional package `nvidia-driver-410` from Ubuntu 19.04 repositories didn't make it easy.

First, add the drivers ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

You can also add NVidia's official CUDA repository which include the drivers, but there is no Ubuntu 19.04 version at the moment (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Then find the version of the 410 drivers available in the ppa:

```
$ apt policy nvidia-dkms-410
nvidia-dkms-410:
  Installed: 410.104-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 418.56-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     418.56-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/ubuntu disco/restricted amd64 Packages
     410.104-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Note that the first package has `418` in its version name because it's actually a transitional package for the `nvidia-driver-418`. Yes, package `nvidia-driver-410` actually installs `nvidia-driver-418`. No idea why, but this is common pattern for all NVidia drivers on debian distros.

We copy the version name of the second package, i.e. `410.104-0ubuntu1`. We could now use it to install the real 410 driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410=410.104-0ubuntu1
```

The explicit version specification is required because the transitional package is chosen by default. BE CAREFUL THOUGH! This may propose you to install 418 packages anyway. Read the additional package list carefully! I don't know whether it is the best solution but I solved it by explicitly overriding every 418 package in my request with 410 equivalents:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-compute-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-encode-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 nvidia-dkms-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-gl-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 nvidia-kernel-source-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 nvidia-compute-utils-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-decode-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 nvidia-utils-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-cfg1-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-ifr1-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-fbc1-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 libnvidia-common-410=410.104-0ubuntu1 nvidia-kernel-common-410=410.104-0ubuntu1
```

E.g. when apt proposed `nvidia-kernel-common-418` I added `nvidia-kernel-common-410=410.104-0ubuntu1` to my command. Tiresome but effective. It would be probably easier to somehow change the priorities of the repositories but I had no idea how to do it.

EDIT:

As pointed out by @fkraiem we can alternatively prioritize the ppa repository to avoid such a long command.

Create a file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/graphics-drivers`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers                            
Pin-Priority: 700
```

Now issue the command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410
```

The PPA repository which contains the real driver package (rather than the transitional package for 418) is now preferred so the driver meta package and all dependencies are installed correctly.

Comment: You can use apt-pinning to tell Apt to disregard versions of `nvidia-driver-410` other than `410.*`.

Comment: @fkraiem, thanks, I've included it in the answer.